# How to iterate through a Perl PDL piddle?

Tags: perl, pdl

The closest I got to was something like

```
use PDL;
my $u = pdl [1,2,3,4];
my $dim = 4;
for(my $i=0; $i<$dim; $i++)
{
  print $u->flat->index($i), "\n";
}
```

Also as I can convert `[1,2,3,4]` to piddle `$u`, can I get back a list (or a list of lists for a matrix) from `$u`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the wisdom from the monks, I found the answer:
http://perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=892201

Thought I'd share it here in my original question.
The above code can be rewritten as:

```
use PDL;
my $u = pdl [1,2,3,4];
foreach ($u->dog)
{
  print $_, "\n";
}
```

The *wisdom* came with a disclaimer that `dog()` works only on small piddles (object).

Comment: There is no limit to what `dog` can work with. I would say that if you are considering looping over a PDL ndarray, you should probably reconsider doing what you're doing in a "vectorised" way.

Answer (score 4):

besides using dog, here are two other options for your 1d pdl using index and list.  there is also index2d

```
use PDL;
my $a = pdl(1 .. 4);
#use index
print $a->index($_), "\n" foreach (0 .. $a->nelem-1);
#use list
print $_ . "\n" foreach ($a->list);
```

Comment: I would use `$a->at($_)` or `$a->sclr($_)`. The `index` method returns a one-entry PDL object, whereas `at` and `sclr` return a Perl scalar. Furthermore, `sclr` is a bit more forgiving than `at`.